# CSS create layers without using position:absolute (make container big enough for all layers)

Tags: html, css

Please see [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Xx6/). UPDATE: answer looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Xx6/28/).

Here I want the `#container` element to be big enough to contain the `#sometimes_shown` layer, but it gets its size from the `#always_shown` child only.

`position:absolute` removes `#sometimes_shown` from the flow, and this aspect of the standard gets mentioned when other people have similar problems.

My question is: can I create the same **layer effect without using `position:absolute`**, thereby including the size of all child layers in the parent's flow logic?

Precomputed widths/heights/offsets are not an option: this has to flow dynamically. I won't accept any solution which contains a dimensioned number other than zero. CSS-only solutions are strongly preferred, compatibility with old browsers is *not* a priority, jQuery/javascript solutions are a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: Absolute positioning removes the element from the regular flow, which means you would have to give other elements a margin-top of *at least* the height of the absolutely positioned element.

Comment: Did you read the whole question?

Comment: Yes, I did. Been looking it up, and aside from using jQuery's `.height` method to calculate the height of all elements, I can't seem to find any other option. Since it removes the div from the flow, you can't use it's height in CSS-only methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **floats**.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Xx6/16/)** (I deleted all your margins for the test)

This solution needs some html markup changes and you will have to use `margin-left: -100%;` on `#sometimes_shown` .

How it works :

- put both `div`s in a wrapper with `width:50%;` and `float:left;` so both elements are on the same line.
- get the elements with back to normal width adding `width:200%;` to `#always_shown` and `#sometimes_shown`
- Add `margin-left: -100%;` to `#sometimes_shown` so it stacks to the left of container
- add a dummy `div` with `clear:both;` at the bottom of the container so it wraps around the floated elements

Here is the code:

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="always_shown">
            <p>I am always here 1. I am always here 2. I am always here 3. I am always here 4. I am always here 5. I am always here 6. I am always here 7.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="sometimes_shown">
            <p>I am sometimes here</p>
             <p>Extra 1</p>
             <p>Extra 2</p>
             <p>Extra 3</p>
             <p>Extra 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container
{
    border: thin solid black;
}

#always_shown
{
    width: 200%; 
    color: red;
}

#sometimes_shown
{
    width: 200%; 
    margin-left: -100%;
    color: green;
}
.wrap{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.clr{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @spraff I am working to put the margins back do you need to keep the ex unit on them?

Comment: This looks pretty good at first glance. Can you explain how it works please?

Comment: @spraff I gave some explanation. Do you still need the margins?

Comment: It doesn't work because it float the .clr div too taking it out of the document flow.